# How to move pong paddle with java.Swing?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, 2d-games

I'm trying to make Pong with Java and Swing. However, I have two problems - one, the rectangle on-screen doesn't move at all, and two, a NullPointerException is happening even though the code still runs. Here are my two files:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Pong extends JFrame implements KeyListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5782301423436L;

    JPanel panel;

    Paddle paddle1;

    public Pong() {
        super("Pong");

        panel = new JPanel();
        this.add(panel);

        super.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
        super.setVisible(true);
        super.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        super.pack();
        addKeyListener(this);

        paddle1 = new Paddle(100, 300);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        Pong game = new Pong();
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);

        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 600);

        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        this.paddle1.draw(g);
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}

    // I've tested this part and the w and s key presses
    // are still detected, but nothing happens. Why not?
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
        int key = keyEvent.getKeyCode();
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE) {
            this.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(this, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
        } else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
            this.paddle1.up();
        } else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
            this.paddle1.down();
        }
    }

}
```

```
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Paddle {

    // Position of the paddle's center
    int x;
    int y;

    public Paddle(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        g.fillRect(this.x - 10, this.y - 40, 20, 80);
    }

    // Up is negative because Java coordinates

    public void up() {
        this.y -= 30;
    }

    public void down() {
        this.y += 30;
    }

}
```

I've tested the keyPressed method in the Pong file, and when the w and s keys are pressed, it does, in fact, detect them (it will print a line out to the console). I'm very new to graphics in Java, and this is the first thing I've tried creating that's not copy-pasted from a tutorial on YouTube. I've been looking at my code for about an hour and can't find where the error could possibly be. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: *a NullPointerException is happening* - one question at a time. First fix the NPE. The stack trace will tell you the statement causing the problem. So look at the statement and figure out which variable is null and fix the problem. Having said that there are several problems with your code: 1) Don't override paint() on the JFrame. Custom painting is done by overriding paintComponent() on a JPanel, then you add the panel to the frame. Read the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and working examples.

Comment: 2) Don't use a KeyListener to listen for KeyEvents. See: [Motion Using the Keyboard](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/) for more information and solutions.

Comment: Typically you want to `setVisible(true);` at the end of the constructor when everything is set up and ready to show. You certainly do not want to `setVisible(true);` before `paddle1 = new Paddle(100, 300);`

Comment: In an animation, nothing "moves".  You erase and redraw the image 30 to 60 times a second to give the appearance of animation.

Answer (score 0):

I've checked the code and can help you solve the errors.

First, here you've shown the Paddle using paint() method of the JFrame **Pong**. You're detecting the 'W' and 'S' keys and according to the key you've written the code to update the y co-ordinate in the Paddle class.

But, the problem here is, you're just updating the y co-ordinate. You're not drawing the paddle with new co-ordinates again. So, after setting the new y value, you should draw the paddle again. 
So, in the keyPressed() method, after

```
this.paddle1.up();
```

and

```
this.paddle1.down();
```

you should again call the draw() method of the Paddle class that will draw the Paddle at the modified location.

In this draw() method you're passing a Graphics object which is the graphics configuration of the current JFrame Pong. So, this can be get using getGraphics() method of the JFrame.

So, the line to add after up() or down() will be

```
this.paddle1.draw(getGraphics());
```

Since we are dealing with graphics, it is also the proper thing to repaint the JFrame once you change something in its graphics. If you have added only the above line after up() and down() method in the keyPressed() method, you will see the Paddle is not moving. Its previous drawing will be as it is and as per the key pressed, new Paddle will be drawn upwards or downwards. So, instead of a moving paddle you will see a vertical bar. This is happening because we are modifying the graphics but not painting the JFrame again. So, it will just add the new rectangle in the JFrame keeping previous as it is.
So, to get rid of this, you should use repaint() method of the JFrame so that it draws only the latest screen.

So, the complete keyPressed() method would be like :

```
@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
    int key = keyEvent.getKeyCode();
    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE) {
        this.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(this, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
    } else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
        this.paddle1.up();
        this.paddle1.draw(getGraphics());
        repaint();
    } else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
        this.paddle1.down();
        this.paddle1.draw(getGraphics());
        repaint();
    }
}
```

So, now after detecting correct keys, it is drawing the paddle again and 
after that discards the previous ones as well so that while you will run this code, you will be able to see the paddle is moving as per the key pressed.

Now, about the NullPointerException. I tried to run this code but I could not reproduce such exception. So, after trying the suggested code, if you encounter NPE, you can update the stack trace to get it solved.

I have read the comments and they are very useful. Do check the link that explains better way for listening to the key events.

Thank you.